Having trouble starting an expo project from terminal
running npx create expo-app brings this error
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/baguma/.npm/_logs/2024-07-19T22_13_39_732Z-debug-0.log

I have tried deleting the node-modules folder and package_lock.json files as a previous S.O answer suggested. Still doesn't work
